# Установка Jupyter Notebook v7

Tags: установка, jupyter-notebook

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом, как установить Jupyter Notebook v7. Сейчас у меня версия 6.5.4, среда Anaconda 2023.07-2 и pip 23.2.1. [Инструкции по установке читал](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/install.html), но обновление прошло только до версии 6.5.4.
Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Хмм... У меня и вовсем 5.7.8, никаких обновлений не показывает. Но, последнюю версию можно всегда с [github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) поставить через локальную репу. Ну и собственно там же есть ссылка на версию 7, где говорится, что она будет очень непохожа на прошлую, база от JupyterLab, а для тех кто привык к старому ноутбуку есть RetroLab. Думаю для установки этой major версии надо смотреть в сторону JupyterLab, а старый ноутбук выше 6.*.* и не обновится никогда.

Comment: `pip install -U jupyter` не дало вообще ничего, а вот `pip install -U notebook` апгрейднуло до версии **6.5.5**, чуть выше чем у вас.

Comment: Ну и если запустить `pip index versions notebook`, то седьмой там и в помине нет. До сих пор в тесте? Видимо. Т.к. в этом [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6802) ставят альфа версию в марте, и не без проблем.

Comment: Ну собственно, да. `pip index version notebook --pre` показывает **7.0.0a11**, из альфы пока не вышли, поэтому без `--pre` не показывает и не ставит по дефолту. `pip install notebook --pre` поставит альфа версию, либо же можно указать конкретную из списка `pip install notebook==7.0.0a11`, хотя на Github версия **7.0.3**, вроде как стабильная даже, почему бы сразу оттуда не взять? Но нужен Python 3.12, у меня явно старее. В конде процесс должен быть приблизительно тот же, смотрите какие там версии через **conda search**.

Comment: Спасибо запредложения. Я попробовал `pip index versions notebook` у меня отобразилась в списке версия 7.0.3.

Comment: @DiMithras, спасибо Вам. У меня получилость установить 7.0.3.

Comment: Отлично. Возможно попозже попробую оформить в ответ.